# Format text into a shape

Tags: php, css

I need to format a small string of text so that it will display inside a circle - example http://stredtech.co.uk/YMD/

It needs to be done in php

any suggestions?

Comment: Try to give the text in div and change its border radius

Comment: -1 because you showed no effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *Live Demo*

Use this `html`

```
<div class="circleBase type6"><i>We honestly <br>
feel that whilst YMD <br>are acting on our behalf<br>
we will receive the best <br>deal for the future.</i> 
<br><br>Mr. and Mrs. C <br>Essex</div>
```

And this `css`

```
.type6 {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: #606062;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
color: white;
}
.circleBase {
-webkit-border-radius: 999px;
-moz-border-radius: 999px;
border-radius: 999px;
}
```

Comment: yes, it needs to be dynamically generated. so any string could be used. - Awesome code that you linked there!

Comment: @OllyStredwick Put your string inside `<div class="circleBase type6"></div>`. It will work. :)

Comment: I want to avoid using the <br /> tags as the data will be entered into a database by a secretary and then pulled out via php.

Comment: @OllyStredwick You can use any string here, I have use it just to demonstrate you. And accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: It does work, but just does not look as neat. Thanks anyway